# Cannot install glut for Dev-c++ on windows 64 bit

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I want to install glut library for Dev-c++, I do the following:

- Download and install Dev-c++ from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Setup%20Releases/), (Dev-Cpp 5.7.1 TDM-GCC x64 4.8.1 Setup.exe)
- Add glut from: Tool -> Check for
  Packages... -> install glut 3.7.6    from Devpak site    
  (Base working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp)
- Copy `glut.h, glutf90.h` from `include\GL` to `MinGW64\include\GL` and
  `MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\GL` (I don't know where is the correct folder so I add to somewhere else...)
- Copy `libglut32.a` from `lib\` to `MinGW64\lib` (reference from youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dpcUhNSMzg))
- Open Dev-c++ and
  Create an empty C++ project, add these options to project Linker Parameters:
  `-lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32`
- Add some file, like this:

//*Lab01_Perimitives.cpp*

```
/* -- INCLUDE FILES ------------------------------------------------------ */
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <gl/glu.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>


/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */


void myInit( void )  {
  glClearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  glPointSize( 3.0 );
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity( );
  glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
void myDisplay( void )  {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT ); 

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);      
            glVertex3f(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
            glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);          
            glVertex3f(0.75, 0.25, 0.0);
            glColor3f(0.5f,0.5f,1.0f);              
            glVertex3f(0.75, 0.75, 0.0);
            glColor3f(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);          
            glVertex3f(0.25, 0.75, 0.0);

        glEnd();

        glutSwapBuffers();

}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
  // Initialize GLUT.
  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  // Set the mode to draw in.
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB );
  // Set the window size in screen pixels.
  glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
  // Set the window position in screen pixels.
  glutInitWindowPosition( 100, 150 );
  // Create the window.
  glutCreateWindow( "Lab01" );
  // Set the callback funcion to call when we need to draw something.


  myInit( );
  glutDisplayFunc( myDisplay );
  // Initialize some things.
  // Now that we have set everything up, loop responding to events.
  glutMainLoop( );
}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

But when I compile I get these error:

```
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libglut32.a when searching for -lglut32
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible c:/program files (x86)/dev-cpp/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../lib/libglut32.a when searching for -lglut32
...etc...
c:\program files (x86)\dev-cpp\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    cannot find -lglut32
E:\Mon hoc\Do hoa may tinh\Lab01\collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
E:\Mon hoc\Do hoa may tinh\Lab01\Makefile.win   recipe for target 'Lab01.exe' failed
```

What is problem here, how to fix it?
My computer is running Windows 8.1 64 bit

Comment: I suggest you download the source-code for freeglut and build a 64-bit library from it. Copying a 32bit library into the 64bit lib folder isn't going to do the trick, as the first 2 lines of your error log clearly demonstrates. Freeglut has always proved to be a drop-in replacement for me - never tried to build it for x64 though, so I don't know if this will build, or if there are parts of the code that aren't conducive to a 64bit build.